# I can't reset sensitive app permissions declaration on Google Play console

Tags: android, google-play, react-native, google-play-console

I have been facing an issue for almost 3 weeks now and I am kind of desperate about it...
Indeed, I have released an application but I filled out the "sensitive app permissions declaration" by mistake.

3 weeks later and all of my 5 app updates have been rejected by Google Play, with of course no way to reach Google Developer assistance (I believe it does not even exist, they are so incompetent...) I always get an automatically generated reply telling me that my app uses ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION which it does NOT...

My question now is how do I remove the declaration to state that I do not use location services ? Or what can I do so that my updates stop being rejected for no reason ?

I have already tried to file an appeal but I get the exact same response generated by a machine telling me that my app uses location and that the description is unclear...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I found out that I have to update the build on every track (Open testing, Closed testing, Production, etc.) even if they are disabled.

More info in this: https://bapspatil.medium.com/dear-googles-permissions-declaration-form-can-we-break-up-85bc6b62f690